# Password in c++ | Deleting a character after printing it

Tags: c++, passwords, stdout, password-protection

When we type password in websites ,we see * or . instead of characters.How can this be made possible with c++.Suppose I am trying to input password through stdin and at the same time I am storing it in a char array and deleting the character input by the user and outputing * instead.I think deleting the character is the trick here.But how do we delete a character after having printed it via stdout.

Comment: You should not print the character in the first place.

Comment: I am not printing the character.When I input the character is visible on the screen right ?I just want to delete that character and print a * instead.

Comment: What is your operating system? What libraries do you use?

Comment: No need to output `*`. Do it the unix-terminal-way and display nothing, so the length can not be guessed from screen reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the key with `_getch()` (header `<conio.h>`), save/process it, and print '*' character instead of it. `<conio.h>` is available only on Windows afaik, though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the operating system and relevant libraries (the C++ standard does not define anything related to that).

On Linux, you might use `ncurses` or `readline` libraries (on the terminal). And if coding a GUI application, your toolkit (eg Qt) provides a relevant widget.

Answer (score 0):

On this page [C++ password in console](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/3570/) you can find the answer. They use `conio.h` library, but in the middle of this page there is a **better** solution for Windows.